# Layout Space at the bottom

Tags: jquery, html, css

There seems to be some problem with my layout. After the Body tag there seems to be a lot of space automatically appended. It seems to be because of some jQuery Plugin. Can some one help me out.

Comment: If you can [edit] and include images, HTML and/or CSS rather than a link to your page (i.e., "debug my website for me"), please flag and request your question to be reopened.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
#footer {
    background: url("../images/topNav.jpg") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    clear: both;
    color: #EEEEEE;
    margin-top: 42px;
    width: 100%;
    position: static;
}
```

That'll fix your problem. 
Edit: removed "position: absolute; bottom: 0" from the existing CSS definition.
Edit 2: added position: static;

Comment: that didnt the job yeet. there is still some space at the bottom

Comment: not sure why, because it fixed when I checked with firebug. try adding "position: static;" to the above code.

Comment: @HarshaMV I checked on all the browsers (IE9, Chrome 18.0+, Firefox 12.0). Removing "position: absolute;" alone fixed the problem. Can you please update the website ? So that it'll be easier to see what else is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome Inspector shows warning like following:

Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type font/woff: **movie_add.html:301**

"http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/cuprum/v4/sp1_LTSOMWWV0K5VTuZzvQ.woff".

**NOTE:** click on ***movie_add.html:301*** then you will see something and I think this will help you.